# Want to use selenium-webdriver at create-react-app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, selenium-webdriver, create-react-app

I want to use selenium-webdriver at React.
So `npx create-react-app my-app` to create react app. And use `npm i selenium-webdriver` to use selenium-webdriver.
Next download chromedriver.

I want to test Selenium, So write App.js like this.

```
import React from 'react';

const webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');

class App extends React.Component {
  getSelenium = () => {
    var driver = new webdriver.Builder()
      .withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.chrome())
      .build();

    var url = 'https://www.google.com/';
    driver.get(url);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <p>hello</p>
          <button onClick={this.getSelenium}>button</button>
        </header>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

and `npm start` to show develop mode. But I got an error this.

```
./node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js
Module not found: Can't resolve '../../../../bazel-genfiles' in 'C:\Users\COM\hiimDashboard\dashboard\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib'
```

Why did I got this error? What is bazel-genfiles??

Comment: But your React app is clientside application, how you wan't open browser in browser?

Comment: 'selenium-webdriver' is Node.js package, it's mean server side, if you want open webpage at your app, you should use iframe.

Comment: Ah...?! I think that click the buttons then start selenium and open brower in brower. It can't be working?? cant' open browser in browser?

Comment: Of course not, imagine if any site can run any application on your computer without asking?

Comment: Ah ha!! thank you. I wan't not just open webpage in browser. Want crawling page with selenium.

Comment: Then you should use Node.js environment, just google something like `nodejs selenium example`

Comment: Thank you!! I should restart at Node.js environment. not react.js.